# Argmax function in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make armgax function in C++

For example,

```
C = wage * hour * shock + t + a * R + (1 - delta) * d - d_f - a_f - fx1 * (1 - delta) * d;
double result;
result = (1 / (1 - sig)) * pow(pow(C, psi) * pow(d, 1 - psi), (1 - sig));
```

Suppose every variable except for 'd_f' and 'a_f' are given and both 'd_f' and 'a_f' some number(double) in [0, 24].

If I want to get the combination of 'd_f' and 'a_f' that maximizes 'result', is there a proper function that I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there a function in the C++ standard library that would maximize it for you? No. Is there a function in some library somewhere that would do it? Probably.